# Copias de seguridad con google drive

Tags: android

he visto que algunas app como whatsapp permiten hacer copias de seguridad con google drive. Y si accedes a google drive te aparecen todas las copias de seguridad que tienes almacenadas en el. He estado buscando por internet pero no hay nada sobre esto y me gustaria implementarlo en mi aplicación. ¿Sabeis como va o donde hay documentación sobre esto?

Gracias y un saludo

[image: Captura de pantalla de google drive]

Comment: tal cual como lo planteas, tu pregunta es muy amplia, y posiblemente sea cerrada por esa razón.

Comment: Si, tenes que usar la API de google drive para guardar archivos ahí,
te paso la direccion: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!